# How to open glassfish admin UI (console) in AWS ElasticBeansTalk installed with glassfish 4.1 java 8?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, glassfish, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed my war file on AWS ElasticBeanstalk (setup with glassfish4.1 java 1.8). I want to open glassfish admin UI in browser.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you manage to access the console ? I am thinking about switching my managed EC2 to elastic beanstalk, but configuration via console access is a mandatory option for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure its possible to access the glassfish console UI (at least I never went to this point so far, but might be possible using docker forward port ...)

what I do is the following:

- SSH into the ec2 instance elastic beanstalk has provisioned
- run `sudo docker ps -a` to find out about the container running on the instance
- ssh into the container `sudo docker exec -it <container id here> bash`
- this will log you on the container running glassfish, from there you can run the `asadmin` command

Comment: Thanks Frederic! It helped a little...but I want to work on the UI.